# Whether eval() better than self-analysis?

Tags: python, eval

Here is my situation, I have a string as follows

```
'a':1 'b':2 'c':3
```

I want to turn this to a dict, so I have two options:

1. Split the string by `' '` and then by `':'` then put the pairs to a `dict`.
2. Replace `' '` with `','`, append `'{'`, and `'}'` to string and use `eval()` to get a `dict`.

So my question is which one is faster?

Comment: If your string only has three pairs then speed should not be your concern. How big is the real data string?

Comment: Hard to say, that depends on how you put the pairs in a dict, your Python interpreter and your machine. Did you try measuring this?

Comment: Replace the `evi^Hal` in your second point with `ast.literal_eval` and you're safe.

Comment: you can use `timeit`to test the speed

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
import ast
result = ast.literal_eval(''.join(["{", s.replace(" ", ", "), "}"]))
```

You can also do this (although the difference may be negligible):

```
import ast
result = ast.literal_eval("{" + s.replace(" ", ", ") + "}")
```

It's better to use `ast.literal_eval` as [it's safer](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) for this purpose than using `eval()`.

Comment: This is the slowest method of all suggested so far.

Answer (score 6):

Ok, here are all of them so far:

```
import ast, re, json

s = "'a':1 'b':2 'c':3"

def a_eval(s):
    s = s.replace(' ', ',')
    return eval('{%s}' % s)

def a_ast(s):
    s = s.replace(' ', ',')
    return ast.literal_eval('{%s}' % s)

def a_parse(s):
    d = {}
    for p in s.split():
        k, v = p.split(':')
        d[k.strip("'")] = int(v)
    return d

def a_re(s):
    d = []
    re.sub(r"'(\w+)':(\w+)", lambda m: d.append(m.groups()), s)
    return dict((a, int(b)) for a, b in d)

def a_json(s):
    s = s.replace(' ', ',')
    s = s.replace("'", '"')
    return json.loads('{%s}' % s)

#eof

import timeit    
setup = open(__file__).read().split('#eof')[0]
results = []

for p in dir():
    if p.startswith('a_'):
        results.append((timeit.timeit('%s(s)' % p, setup, number=10000), p))

for p in sorted(results):
    print '%.4f %s' % p
```

Results:

```
0.0753 a_parse
0.1068 a_json
0.1455 a_re
0.2211 a_eval
0.3297 a_ast
```

And on longer strings, `json` is the winner:

```
long_s = ((s + ' ') * 100).strip()

for p in dir():
    if p.startswith('a_'):
        results.append((timeit.timeit('%s("%s")' % (p, long_s), setup, number=100), p))

for p in sorted(results):
    print '%.4f %s' % p
```

Results:

```
0.0166 a_json
0.0528 a_parse
0.0565 a_re
0.0927 a_eval
0.1519 a_ast
```

Answer (score 2):

`json.loads` is faster than `ast.literal_eval`:

```
$ python -m timeit -s "s = '\'a\':1 \'b\':2';s = '{' + s.replace(' ', ', ') + '
}'; import json" "json.loads(s.replace('\'', '\"'))"
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.11 usec per loop

$ python -m timeit -s "s = '\'a\':1 \'b\':2';s = '{' + s.replace(' ', ', ') + '
}'; import ast" "ast.literal_eval(s)"
100000 loops, best of 3: 19.4 usec per loop
```

Comment: Yes, this is indeed the fastest method of all.